# Sum number of occurences of string per row

Tags: python, pandas

I have been trying to search an answer for this and I can't find one - I must be misunderstanding something.

I simply want to sum the number of times a string ("True") occurs per row. The desired output is below:

```
d1 = {'score': ['True', 'True', 'False'], 'score2': ['False', 'True', 'True'], 'total': [1, 2, 1]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d1)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Count occurrences of items in Series in each row of a DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24516361/count-occurrences-of-items-in-series-in-each-row-of-a-dataframe)

Comment: @roganjosh, I'm sure this must be a dup (though I can't find it right now), but I don't think that's the one.

Answer (score 4):

try this,

```
df1['total']= df1.eq('True').sum(axis=1)
```

If df is boolean try this,

```
df1['total']= df1.eq(True).sum(axis=1)
```

For More cleaner way,

```
df1['total']= df1.sum(axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   score score2  total
0   True  False      1
1   True   True      2
2  False   True      1
```

Comment: @SebSilas - Can you remove quote from the True, I mean instead of 'True' try True.

Answer (score 2):

#### String values: [`eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) + [`sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html)

```
df1['total'] = df1[['score', 'score2']].eq('True').sum(1)

print(df1)

   score score2  total
0   True  False      1
1   True   True      2
2  False   True      1
```

#### Boolean values: [`sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html)

No Boolean test needs to be performed in this case:

```
df1['total'] = df1[['score', 'score2']].sum(1)
```

Comment: Hm this also gives me 0 for each row.

Comment: In this case it needed True without quotation marks. Thank you!

Comment: @SebSilas, For Boolean values, you don't need to use `eq`, see update.