# Python Pandas - Is it possible to run a dataframe.query method in combination with a counter

Tags: python, pandas

I am running a fairly complex filter on a dataframe in pandas (I am filtering for passing test results against 67 different thresholds via a dictionary).  In order to do this I have the following:

```
query_string = ' | '.join([f'{k} > {v}' for k , v in dictionary.items()])
test_passes = df.query(query_string, engine='python')
```

Where k is the test name and v is the threshold value.

This is working nicely and I am able to export the rows with test passes to csv.

I am wondering though if there is a way to also attach a column which counts the number of test passes.  So for example if the particular row recorded 1-67 test passes.

Answer (score 1):

So I finally 'solved' with the following, starting after the pandas query originally posted. The original question was for test passes by my use case if actually for test failures which....

```
test_failures = data.query(query_string, engine='python').copy()
```

The copy is to prevent unintentional data manipulation and chaining error messages.

```
for k, row in test_failures.iterrows():
    failure_count=0
    test_count=0
    for key, val in threshold_dict.items():
        test_count +=1
        if row[key] > val:
            failure_count +=1
    test_failures.at[k, 'Test Count'] = test_count
    test_failures.at[k, 'Failure Count'] = failure_count
```

From what I have read iterrows() is not the fastest iterative method but it does provide the index (k) and a data dictionary (row) separately which I found more useful for these purposes than the tuple returned in itertuples().

```
sorted_test_failures = test_failures.sort_values('Failure Count', ascending=False)  

sorted_test_failures.to_csv('failures.csv', encoding='utf8')
```

A little sorting and saving to finish.

I have tested on a dummy data set of (8000 x 66) - it doesn't provide groundbreaking speed but it does the job.  Any improvements would be great!

Comment: Ok I think I want to ask does your dictionary contianing the solutions (aka the 'passing values', have to be a dictionary?  Because I'm thinking that if it too is a pandas dataframe, things could get easier.

Comment: The only reason it's a dictionary is that I like the functionality of key value pairs. I had not considered using another pandas dataframe as the analytical tool. I'll have a look into that to see if it improves performance and analytics.  Thanks @RockAndRoleCoder

Answer (score 0):

This was answered here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24516612/6815750

But to give an example you could do the following:

```
new_df = df.apply(pd.Series.value_counts, axis = 1) #where df is your current dataframe holding the pass/fails

df[new_df.columns] = new_df
```

[image: Example]

Comment: The difficultly is that in my current data frame I don't have a boolean 'pass/fail' but rather values 0.006.  It is these values which I am testing for pass / fail using the external dictionary.

Comment: So to be clear, your dictionary is holding the key vlaues that determine if your dataframes row values are passing?

Comment: Can you upload a sample row from your dataframe?  If the rows are very long, just trim it down to 5 columns, the final resolution should be able to be scaled up to your needs.

Comment: You are totally correct - my dictionary determines if the row values in the dataframe are 'passes' or 'fails'.  I actually found a solution which I will post below...perhaps you can let me know your thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following approach instead:

```
dictionary = {'a':'b', 'b': 'c'}
data = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3], 'b': [ 2,1,2], 'c': [2,1,1] })
test_components = pd.DataFrame([df.loc[:, k] > df.loc[:, v] for k , v in dictionary.items()]).T
# now can inspect what conditions were met in `test_components` variable
condition = test_components.any(axis=1)
data_filtered = data.loc[common_condition, :]
```

Comment: my dictionary is more like {'a': 0.005, 'b': 0.26} with 65 such entries.  my dataframe is thousands of lines with values read from csv.