# Python count of string values in a row of a data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, count, row

Suppose I have a pandas data frame `df` with three columns and each column contains string values of either "a" or "b"

```
Col1 Col2 Col3
 a     b    a
 b     b    a
 a     a    a
 b     a    a
 b     b    b
 a     a    b
```

I want to count the number of times "a" and "b" appear in each **row**. How is this computed?

Comment: What's the output?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Count occurrences of items in Series in each row of a DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24516361/count-occurrences-of-items-in-series-in-each-row-of-a-dataframe)

Comment: @Vadim I closed with dupe mentioned in the above comment. If you feel this has been wrongly closed. Please feel free to comment why. I'll reopen.

Comment: @TõnisPiip Yes it does, weird that I never found that link before

Answer (score 0):

We can use [`pd.value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) with [`df.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)

```
df.apply(pd.value_counts)

   Col1  Col2  Col3
a     3     3     4
b     3     3     2
```

In case, you want apply `values_counts` over axis 1 then use:

```
df.apply(pd.value_counts, axis=1)#.fillna(0) incase you want to eliminate NaNs

     a    b
0  2.0  1.0
1  1.0  2.0
2  3.0  NaN
3  2.0  1.0
4  NaN  3.0
5  2.0  1.0
```

Comment: But, they say count in in each **row**

Comment: @AziMez The linked answer solved what OP is looking for. This answer does exactly the same as the answers linked in the dupe.  But I get point OP has to clarify what the expected output is since, row and column are often confused.

Comment: If you mean **row** as in over axis 1 then `df.apply(pd.value_counts, axis=1)` should do it. @AziMez I'll edit my answer appropriately once OP clarifies or will delete incase they don't.

Comment: *Thank you* for your clarification.  Your response is ** very useful**. You can just EDIT it with this one: **df.apply(pd.value_counts, axis=1)** in the case  of row. Since the question is already closed.

Comment: @AziMez Yes, I edited that into my answer. Thank you.